# replacing a particular pattern in a string with an auto incrementing number

Tags: java

I have a string like `"Hello how Hello are Hello"`
I want to replace the number of times `"Hello"` occurs in the above string by an autoincrementing number.

Such that the result would be: `"1 how 2 are 3"`

`"Hello"` can occur any number of times

Answer (score 1):

I don't know felt the need to do it with recursion.

```
public class StringReplacement {

    private static final String HELLO = "Hello";

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stringToTransform = "Hello how Hello are Hello";
        System.out.println(transform(stringToTransform));
    }

    private static String transform(String stringToTransform) {
        return transform(stringToTransform, 1);
    }

    private static String transform(String stringToTransform, int counter) {

        String output = stringToTransform.replaceFirst(HELLO, String
                .valueOf(counter));

        if (output.contains(HELLO))
            return transform(output, ++counter);
        else
            return output;
    }

}
```

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use recursion." Now they have two problems. :D

Comment: The "contains()" method on string is giving compilation errors.
Plz Help..!!

Comment: You didn't note that you were using 1.3 before, it is a prety important detail. Just switch the if to "output.indexof(HELLO) != -1"

Answer (score 0):

try this simple method:

```
public static String transform(String input) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 1;

    for (String s : input.split("Hello")) {
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %d", s, i++));
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

### Sample usage

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String i = "Hello how Hello are Hello";
    System.out.println(transform(i));
}
```

Comment: I was actually wanting something different ...i am sorry to put up the question incorrectly
i want it something like this 

"Hello1ok how Hello2ok are Hello3ok"

plz help

Comment: Your testcase doesn't test anything. How do you know the tested function works?

Comment: Hi i am using JDK 1.3  so it doesn't support "String.format"  
Plz suggest

Comment: @Gourav: so you must use `StringBuffer`, not `StringBuilder` and do something like in place of `String.format`: `stringBuffer.append(s).append(' ').append(String.valueOf(i++))`;